# Angular using a Subject .next() doesn't seem to triger the subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

So i have a service  with the following code

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class FileService {
    private localfiles: UploadedFile[] = [new UploadedFile('asdasd', 'sdfsdfsd', false, 1, 2, 'dsfsf')];

    filesChanged = new Subject<UploadedFile[]>();

    constructor() {}

    setFiles(file: UploadedFile) {
        this.localfiles.push(file)
        console.log(this.localfiles)
        this.filesChanged.next(this.localfiles.slice())
        console.log('after')
    }
```

I then have a component as follows

```
export class FileslistComponent implements OnInit {

  files: UploadedFile[];

  constructor(private fileService: FileService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.files = this.fileService.getFiles();
    this.fileService.filesChanged.subscribe((files: UploadedFile[])=>{
      console.log('never gets here')
      this.files = files;
    })
  }

}
```

When I call setFiles the array is updated as can bee seen from the console log of the array.  But the console log inside the subscribe within the component is never display and the array there isn't updated.

Comment: What happens when you do the subscribe before the getFiles call?

Comment: Still the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. It's amazing what a nights sleep will do.  I'd started providing the service at component level. Later changed my mind and moved it to root, but forgot to stop providing it at component, and so as such had 2 different versions of the service.

Removed the provision at component level and all now works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're calling the `setFiles` functions before initializing the component or subscribing to the `filesChanged` . So, it's better in such cases to use [BehaviorSubject](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject) instead of normal `Subject`, which will keep the latest emitted value within its buffer to pass it to the subscribers that come after emitting the value.

**P.S.** If you don't want to allow the consumers of the service to emit new values to the `Subject`, it's better to expose it as observable using the [Subject.asObservable()](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subject#asObservable) function.

Comment: Thanks i'll give that a try but the setFiles is called after a form is submitted once the component is already displayed

Comment: So tried BehavioySubjects this calls the subscribe after initialization but not on subsequent calls to setFiles.

Comment: In order to have subsequent calls are you triggering setFiles method anywhere? you need to call next method in the behavior subject to have it trigger the subscription

Answer (score 0):

this is because however `subscribe` to `subject` will not get the last value of it, only from now on. so it looks like your component initializes after following the method called so the `subscribe` will not trigger this time.
you can use `behaviorSubject` instead - this one return the last omitted value when subscribing to it.
check this out [behaviorSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject)